# New install of ubuntu server, SSD IOPS are very slow

Tags: ssd, sata

I just installed ubuntu-server 22.04.1 on a Samsung 870 QVO 2TB. Testing with fio I am getting very slow IOPS, but am only getting r=3100, w=1200 IOPS. Which seems much lower than I should be getting. Any ideas?  I did verify it is using SATA3 link.

```
sudo fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test --filename=test --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=1G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75


test: (g=0): rw=randrw, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=64
fio-3.28
Starting 1 process
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [m(1)][100.0%][r=14.2MiB/s,w=4716KiB/s][r=3631,w=1179 IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
test: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=1206: Sun Sep 25 11:36:07 2022
  read: IOPS=3600, BW=14.1MiB/s (14.7MB/s)(768MiB/54580msec)
   bw (  KiB/s): min=12808, max=15304, per=100.00%, avg=14405.21, stdev=316.65, samples=109
   iops        : min= 3202, max= 3826, avg=3601.30, stdev=79.18, samples=109
  write: IOPS=1202, BW=4811KiB/s (4926kB/s)(256MiB/54580msec); 0 zone resets
   bw (  KiB/s): min= 4280, max= 5464, per=100.00%, avg=4812.33, stdev=219.14, samples=109
   iops        : min= 1070, max= 1366, avg=1203.08, stdev=54.79, samples=109
  cpu          : usr=1.37%, sys=27.04%, ctx=261891, majf=0, minf=7
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.1%, >=64=100.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.1%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=196498,65646,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=64

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=14.1MiB/s (14.7MB/s), 14.1MiB/s-14.1MiB/s (14.7MB/s-14.7MB/s), io=768MiB (805MB), run=54580-54580msec
  WRITE: bw=4811KiB/s (4926kB/s), 4811KiB/s-4811KiB/s (4926kB/s-4926kB/s), io=256MiB (269MB), run=54580-54580msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  sda: ios=195694/65460, merge=71/35, ticks=78794/11545, in_queue=90360, util=99.88%
```

Comment: Do you have latest firmware? `udisksctl status` & if newer bootable ISO download it. Check firmware not Magician unless you have Windows. https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue in the BIOS. SATA was setup to use ATA instead of ACHI mode. Now I am getting 80k IOPS